# Read csv with multiline text columns by dask

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, dask, dask-dataframe

I have to read csv which contains full text data, which can be multiline. I am able to read this csv by pure pandas (tested on version `0.25.3` and `1.0.3`) without any problems but when i try to read this csv by dask i receive `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 28` the row number depends on file which i try to read.

I prepared the artificial dataframe to reproduce this error. Can i something tune in dask parameters, preprocess input file or this is dask implementation issue?

```
multiplication_factor = 71 # 70 works fine, 71 fail
number_of_columns = 100

import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import textwrap

pandas_default_kwargs = {    
    'cache_dates': True,
#     'chunksize': None, # not support by dask
    'comment': None,
#     'compression': 'infer', # not support by dask
    'converters': None,
    'date_parser': None,
    'dayfirst': False,
    'decimal': b'.',
    'delim_whitespace': False,
    'delimiter': None,
    'dialect': None,
    'doublequote': True,
    'dtype': object,
    'encoding': None,
    'engine': None,
    'error_bad_lines': True,
    'escapechar': None,
    'false_values': None,
    'float_precision': None,
    'header': 'infer',
#     'index_col': None, # not support by dask
    'infer_datetime_format': False,
#     'iterator': False, # not support by dask
    'keep_date_col': False,
    'keep_default_na': True,
    'lineterminator': None,
    'low_memory': True,
    'mangle_dupe_cols': True,
    'memory_map': False,
    'na_filter': True,
    'na_values': None,
    'names': None,
    'nrows': None,
    'parse_dates': False,
    'prefix': None,
    'quotechar': '"',
    'quoting': 0,
    'sep': ',',
    'skip_blank_lines': True,
    'skipfooter': 0,
    'skipinitialspace': False,
    'skiprows': None,
    'squeeze': False,
    'thousands': None,
    'true_values': None,
    'usecols': None,
    'verbose': False,
    'warn_bad_lines': True,
}

artificial_df_1_row = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        (
            textwrap.dedent(
                f"""
                some_data_for
                
                column_number_{i}
                """
            )
            for i 
            in range(number_of_columns)
        )
    ],
    columns=[f'column_name_number_{i}' for i in range(number_of_columns)]
)

path_to_single_line_csv = './single_line.csv'
path_to_multi_line_csv = './multi_line.csv'

# prepare data to save
single_line_df = artificial_df_1_row
multi_line_df = pd.concat(
    [single_line_df] * multiplication_factor,
)

# save data
single_line_df.to_csv(path_to_single_line_csv, index=False)
multi_line_df.to_csv(path_to_multi_line_csv, index=False)

# read 1 row csv by dask - works
dask_single_line_df = dd.read_csv(
    path_to_single_line_csv, 
    blocksize=None, # read as single block
    **pandas_default_kwargs
)
dask_single_line_df_count = dask_single_line_df.shape[0].compute()
print('[DASK] single line count', dask_single_line_df_count)

# read multiline csv by pandas - works
pandas_multi_line_df = pd.read_csv(
    path_to_multi_line_csv,
    **pandas_default_kwargs
)
pandas_multi_line_df_shape_0 = pandas_multi_line_df.shape[0]
print('[PANDAS] multi line count', pandas_multi_line_df_shape_0)

# read multine csv by dask - depends on number of rows fails or not
dask_multi_line_df = dd.read_csv(
    path_to_multi_line_csv, 
    blocksize=None,  # read as single block
    **pandas_default_kwargs
)
dask_multi_line_df_shape_0 = dask_multi_line_df.shape[0].compute()
print('[DASK] multi line count', dask_multi_line_df_shape_0)
```

Comment: Stack overflow requests that you provide a minimal code sample which, the smallest amount that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The *only* way you can read such a file is to ensure that the chunk boundaries are not within a quoted string which, unless you know a lot about the data layout, means not chunking a file at all (but you can still parallelise between files).

This is because, the only way to know whether or not you are in a quoted string is to parse a file from the start, and the way dask achieves parallelism is to have each chunk-reading task completely independent, needing only a file offset. In practice, dask reads from the offset and considers the first newline marker as the point to start parsing from.